# Get Number of Splines from Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

### Question:

Is there a way, using geometry nodes, to retrieve the number of splines from a curve object? It seems to be a very straightforward question, but I cannot come up with a solution.

### Details:

I'm not sure all of this is relevant, but just in case, here is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm creating some text animations and I have some nodes that morph one curve into another. As the "Factor" from the group input moves from 0 to 1, the initial curve is transformed into the final curve. An example is shown morphing "1+2" into "3+4".

[image: Morph one curve to another.]

[image]

In this example, the initial curve "1+2" has 3 splines. The final curve "3+4" has 4 splines. To ensure the curve ends up looking right after the morph, I add a fourth spline to the initial curve before morphing. This is done by the nodes in the "Add Splines" frame. My issue is, depending on the curves involved I may need to add a different number of splines. I'd like to get the number of splines in the initial and final curves so that I can plug the difference into the "Amount" input of the duplicate geometry node. I can't figure out how to get this information though.

[image]

Comment: i wrote this often - and write it again: to attract more people to your question who don't want to rebuild your node tree manually - it would be a great idea to add your blend file so we can easily and quickly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. Didn't realize I could do that and just figured out how.

Comment: thanks for your blend file - so you atttracted me to answer ;)

Comment: How about the node [Domain Size](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/domain_size.html)?

Comment: @quellenform This works perfectly as well, thanks. Can't believe I missed this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max spline index like this:

[image]

so just add 1 and you get the number of splines.

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten about the attribute statistic node and couldn't figure out how to easily get the max index.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Domain Size* node, in curve mode it has a *Spline Count* output.

The answer of Chris can't differentiate between 1 and 0 splines, since both will result in a max index of 0.

[image: Using Domain Size]

Comment: Yup, it is also more straightforward to use IMO